# How Can I Identify Window Close Event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are multiple windows in my project.I am using angular 1 I want to identify event when user close the window.

I have tried below function but it is not working in Fire Fox and Chrome as well as I am not able detect which window is closed

`$window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        alert("Hi");
};`

Please Help me How can I Identify event when user close particular window also How can I Detect which window is closed?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use $window? I think $window is a jQuery object.

If it is, than you should use $window[ 0 ].onbeforeunload

Comment: @elad.chen $window is not a jquery object, it might be here meant to be a  variable equal to a jquery object.

Comment: @elad.chen I think it is the [`$window` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) of angular, a wrapper around the `window` object of javascript

Comment: Yes $window service is a wrapper around the window obj of javascript

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

Comment: Above code is still not working in FF and Chrome